# Office 365 wrong Document Title in search result

Tags: search, office-365, crawled-property

Office 365 wrong Document Title in search result .

I have configured the search Managed Property like this

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/357997

But still title is comming from document not from item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the problem too. If the document is a PDF, the changes in the crawler-settings won´t help (because the values from the ifilter overrule somehow in the backend).
Anyway, my workarount was to create a calculated column in the list, which simply reflects the value of the "Title"-Field. This way you have the expected Value in the search. Then you can change the display template to not show the "Title" but the Value of your new managed property, or add your new crawled property into the mappings of the "Title"-managed property to the top of the list

Comment: besides: As I had this problem too, i talked to colleagues from MS. They confirmed it as feature (and that we would be the only ones who did not want the "real" titles of the documents in search results)

Comment: You are right. I have to use custom calculated column. MS needs to improve this type of feature. :( . Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

go to Search Schema and search for the "Title" Managed Property and set the mappings to crawled properties shown in the below image

[image]

for more details go through Online Search

Comment: Hi sai... MetadataExtractorTitle is for document title not for Item title